# Cannot find an application associated with the given consumer key : FUlim58xqgf3QMsybitgTPBkrKka

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm learning WSO2 Identity Server Fundamentals - V5.11 now, while runnig the application pickup-dispatch by visiting http://localhost.com:8080/pickup-dispatch/index.jsp. I'm able to go to the page with the pickup-dispatch when i click on the login button , i'm getting the error Cannot find an application associated with the given consumer key : FUlim58xqgf3QMsybitgTPBkrKka, in the dispatch.properties file i have changed the consumer key as per the OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration Oauth Client key & Oauth Client Secret.

i have closed everything and reopened (refreshed) yet i'm receiving this issue. I'm unable to understand where am i going wrong.

Comment: Hi divya, Check whether you have added the correct consumerKey (Client Key) and consumerSecret (Client Secret) in dispatch.properties file. Is `FUlim58xqgf3QMsybitgTPBkrKka` the Client Key in the application registered?

Comment: @divya, Did you restart the tomcat server after changing the consumer key and secret? Also, check whether the consumer key is copied with leading or trailing spaces